# Size of disk/partition in Python is different than linux command

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Using: **Python 3.7.6 , OS Linux** (rmp)

I need to extract total and free sizes of disks and partitions in Python.

I tried different Python functions to retrieve block size in bytes (the results were the same).
Then I compared to results of Linux commands (also in bytes), results were different (Linux commands different than Python).

**Python functions:**

1. Using *os.statvfs*

```
import os 
statvfs  = os.statvfs('/dev/sda')     
statvfs.f_frsize *statvfs.f_blocks   
statvfs.f_frsize * statvfs.f_bfree

Results:
size of /dev/sda is 1973968896
size of /dev/sda1 is 1973968896 (the same??!)
```

2. Using *shutil.disk_usage* :

```
print(shutil.disk_usage('/dev/sda'))
usage(total=1973968896, used=0, free=1973968896)

print(shutil.disk_usage('/dev/sda1') )
usage(total=1973968896, used=0, free=1973968896)
```

I tried also *psutil*:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.disk_usage('/dev/sda'))
print(psutil.disk_usage('/dev/sda1'))
same results as 1. and 2.
```

**Linux command:**

1. *blockdev --getsize64* #Print device size in bytes

```
blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda
8001563222016

blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda1
80014737408
```

2. *lsblk -b*

[image]

What do I miss here ?
Why Python results are different than Linux command (while all units in bytes)?
Why Python sizes of sda and sda1 are the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage and https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.statvfs are used to get stats on filesystem and not a block device, so when you are using `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda1` as argument - you are actually getting info about `/dev`

You can get similar results with `stat` command, here is example with my `/dev/sdb`.

In python:

```
print(shutil.disk_usage('/dev/sdb'))                                                                                                                                                
usage(total=8324083712, used=0, free=8324083712)

print(shutil.disk_usage('/dev'))                                                                                                                                                
usage(total=8324083712, used=0, free=8324083712)
```

In shell:

```
LANG=C stat -f /dev/sdb   
  File: "/dev/sdb"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 2032247    Free: 2032247    Available: 2032247
Inodes: Total: 2032247    Free: 2031625

LANG=C stat -f /dev/   
  File: "/dev/"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 2032247    Free: 2032247    Available: 2032247
Inodes: Total: 2032247    Free: 2031625

echo $(( 2032247 * 4096 ))
8324083712
```

You can see that shutil output and block size * blocks total are exactly the same.

Notice the -f flag:

`-f, --file-system     display file system status instead of file status`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It makes sens. Do you know how to get total and free sizes of disks and partitions in Python ?

Comment: @MariaB, there are several projects, acting as wrapper for cli utils, i.e. https://pypi.org/project/blkinfo/ or https://github.com/dcantrell/pyparted/blob/master/examples/query_device_capacity.py , but i think this is a bit out of scope of current question, you should definitely post another one! If you think your original question is answered - feel free to accept it so others may see it as solved.